# PHP MySQL Data Output

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to read out data from a specific date from a MySQL database.
What I wanted is for PHP to get all of the data from the database within a specific date that I entered, but it seems that the script just got only the first row of data and left out the rest.

Can you please help me with code to achieve this.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['query']))
    {
        $searchQuery = $_POST['data-search'];

        //connceting to db
        $con = mysql_connect($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'root','');
        if(!$con)
        {
            die("Error connecting: ".mysql_error());
            exit;
        }
        //selecting db
        $dbSelect = mysql_select_db("directory",$con);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM websites WHERE Date LIKE '$searchQuery'";
        //executing query
        $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
        if(!$result)
        {
            die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $searchOutput = "<html><body><table border=1><tr><td>Website Title</td><td>Website URL</td><td>About Website Content</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>".$row['Title']."</td><td>".$row['URL']."</td><td>".$row['Content']."</td></tr></table>";
        }
        $searchSuccess = "<p>Your Search was successful</p</body></html>";
        mysql_close($con);
        echo $searchOutput;
        echo $searchSuccess;

    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You realise that your $searchOutput string is being overwritten for every row you've retrieved. Please also make an effort to learn html markup for tables, rows and cells.... the markup itself is completely inconsistent

Comment: And you're starting a new HTML document/body per each row, which is not real valid HTML and might turn out to be rendered bogus from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you replace `$searchOutput` every time it passes through the loop.

**Change:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $searchOutput = "<html><body><table border=1><tr><td>Website Title</td><td>Website URL</td><td>About Website Content</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>".$row['Title']."</td><td>".$row['URL']."</td><td>".$row['Content']."</td></tr></table>";
    }
```

**to:**

```
$searchOutput = "<html><body><table border=1><tr><td>Website Title</td><td>Website URL</td><td>About Website Content</td></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $searchOutput .= "<tr><td>".$row['Title']."</td><td>".$row['URL']."</td><td>".$row['Content']."</td></tr>";
    }

$searchOutput .= "</table>";
```

BTW you should consider refactoring your  code so that all the templating/formatting stuff is separated from the database logic stuff.   It will make it easier to read and maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

you should treat the date column as date, e.g.:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM websites WHERE Date between '$startDate' and '$endDate'";
```

You should use Paramterized Queries instead of using string concatenation to avoid sql injection. I am sure the Mysql documentation has some examples on that.